# Is it possible to use named parameter for Scala case-class matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, wildcard, case-class

Suppose there is a Scala case-class `Point`

```scala
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
```

One can use a wildcard for matching:

```scala
val p = new Point(1,2)
val inRightHalfPlane = p match {
  case Point(x, _) if x>0 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

However, if the number of members increase, one will need to use more wildcards `_`:

```scala
case class Point(
  x0: Int,
  x1: Int,
  x2: Int,
  x3: Int,
  x4: Int,
)


val flag = p match {
  case Point(x,_,_,_,_,) if x>0 => true
  ......
}
```

Is there any syntax sugar like the following code?

```scala
val flag = p match {
  case Point(x0=x) if x>0 => true
  ......
}
```

Comment: `case p: Point if (p.x0) => true` is the closer that I know. I agree it would be better to have something like what you suggested.

Comment: Somewhat related discussion [here](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/pattern-matching-with-named-fields/1829/6).

Comment: ticket of record is https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6524

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define custom `unapply`

```
  case class Point(
                    x0: Int,
                    x1: Int,
                    x2: Int,
                    x3: Int,
                    x4: Int,
                  )

  object PositiveFirst {
    def unapply(p: Point): Option[Int] = if (p.x0 > 0) Some(p.x0) else None
  }

  val p: Point = ???

  val flag = p match {
    case PositiveFirst(x) => true
//      ......
  }
```

Comment: ```
    def unapply(p: Point): Boolean = p.x0 > 0
...
    case PositiveFirst => true

```